# H2O + HDFS (Cloudera)

Tags: hdfs, h2o

We have a Cloudera cluster up and running with an h2o instance although it appears to be running off h2o.jar (which as I understand it--please correct me if incorrect) is the stand-alone h2o.  I can connect, but it will not load any files from our HDFS. (all of this i can see via 'ps' on edge node.

So I started an instance with h2odriver.jar

`java -jar /path/to/h2odriver.jar -nodes 2 -mapperXmx 5g -output /my/hdfs/dir`

I get several output/callback addresses:

`[Possible callback IP address: 10.96.243.46:33728]
[Possible callback IP address: 127.0.0.1]
Using mapper->driver callback IP address and port: 10.96.243.46:33728`

So I fire up python and try and connect (same thing happens if I use 10.96.243.46):

`>>>h2o.connection(ip='127.0.0.1', port='33728')`

and get

```
'Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:33728..... failed.
H2OConnectionError: COuld not estalich link to the H2O cloud http://127.0.0.1:33728 after 5 retries
...
Failed to establish a new connection:[Errno 111] Connection refused',))`
```

Thing is on my screen with the H2O jar/java job I can see:

```
`MapperToDriverMessage: Read invalid type (G) from socket, ignoring...
MapperToDriverMessage: read: Unknown Type `
```

I cannot figure out how to launch h2o in cluster mode and have it access our hdfs system or even connect.  I can connect to the h2o.jar version, but that sees no hdfs (it can see the filesystem of the edgenode).  What is the proper way to launch H2O so that it can see the attached HDFS system (We are running Cloudera 5.7 in a enterprise environment, Python is 3.6, H2O is 3.10.0.6 and I know we have a ton of firewalls/security-- i beleive we are setup through LDAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `h2o.jar` is meant to be the standalone version of H2O which is not meant for connecting to HDFS.

Using the appropriate `h2odriver.jar` for your particular hadoop distribution is the way to go.

The correct beginner instructions can be found here:

- go to http://www.h2o.ai/download/
- choose H2O "Latest Stable Release"
- choose tab "Install on Hadoop"

It says to run the following command:

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output hdfsOutputDirName
```

[ Note this is "hadoop jar", not "java -jar" as written in the question. ]

You should see output like this:

```
Determining driver host interface for mapper->driver callback...
[Possible callback IP address: 172.16.2.181]
[Possible callback IP address: 127.0.0.1]
...
Waiting for H2O cluster to come up...
H2O node 172.16.2.188:54321 requested flatfile
Sending flatfiles to nodes...
[Sending flatfile to node 172.16.2.188:54321]
H2O node 172.16.2.188:54321 reports H2O cluster size 1
H2O cluster (1 nodes) is up
(Note: Use the -disown option to exit the driver after cluster formation)

Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://172.16.2.188:54321

(Press Ctrl-C to kill the cluster)
Blocking until the H2O cluster shuts down...
```

Then point your web browser to the place where it says to "Open H2O Flow in your web browser".

(The other addresses in the output are diagnostics, and not for end users.)

In this case, the python connection command would be:

```
h2o.connect(ip = '172.16.2.188', port = 54321)
```

I recommend going to Flow in a web browser, start importing a file by typing in "hdfs://", and seeing if autocompletion works.  If it does, your HDFS connection is working.

Comment: switching to 'hadoop jar'  did the trick.  I never saw the cluster come up (the "requesting flatfiles portion" ) With that switch, server is up, and I can connect.  Wasn't able to get to Flow as the address is firewall blocked (I suspect), but WAS able to connect through python and confirm I can import through hdfs.  --edit once I figured out the 'name' to the server for flow, I was able to connect through I firewall (address doesn't work--but again firewall, not h2o).